# Typical 404 - File or directory not found?

Tags: c#, hyperlink, http-status-code-404

I read a number of Google and Stackoverflow posts without success.

My c# application sends out emails with a hyperlink in.  The hyperlink address is:

```
http:\\41.xx.xx.x\Documents\logoColourBG.jpg
```

When clicking the hyperlink, I get:

```
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

The subfolder Documents is shared and users IUSR and IIS_IUSRS do have access to it.

Comment: You mention that the folder is shared. Are you trying to link directly to the file in the shred folder without going through a webserver? If so, you would like to the file as file://41.xx.xx.x/Documents/logoColourBG.jpg.

If, however, you are trying to go through a web server (which I am guessing you might be since you mention IIS_IUSRS) you will need to do more than just share that folder, you will need to configure IIS to make that folder available as part of a web site.

Comment: Yes, I guess to go through the webserver is the better option.  Will see if I can make the folder available as part of the site.  Not yet sure how, but will see if I can do that.  Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to access the file directly over the network in windows explorer or so you should try something like this :

> \\41.xx.xx.x\Documents\logoColourBG.jpg

But if you are trying to access it from the browser your request will be handled by IIS or another web server that is installed and configured on the machine.
Then you should set the folder's permissions and sharing options to default and then create a virtual directory like it is explained in [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-pt/library/cc771804%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).